# How can I get and assign the values of my list/array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My Ajax function gets a list from my backend. And I'm trying to assign the value in a variable so I can use it and put the value on my table. How can I get the value from the list/array? I tried something but it won't work. What is the right way to do it?

Here is my jQuery snippet:

```
$('#trigger').click(function(){
    var send = $('#myselect').val();
    $.ajax({

        data:{
          sent: send
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/delinquincy'
    })
    .done(function(data){
      q1=data[1]
      q2=data[2]
      q3=data[3]
      q4=data[4]

      $('#q1').html(q1)
      $('#q2').html(q2)
      $('#q3').html(q3)
      $('#q4').html(q4)
    })
  })
```

Comment: Whats the format of `data`? Try `console.log(data);` and see what is the format.

Comment: Please return json array and than parse in jquery with jQuery.parseJSON() function

Comment: Please check format of `data` and tell us? use `console.log(data);` and show us it's output (add that output in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check your response dataformat. if its array convert it in json.

use  `dataType:'json'`

But before you should check your response format.